# IIS_IUSRS group is removed from "Impersonate a client after authentication" Local Security Policy

Tags: iis-10, windows-server-2019

On a Windows 2019 server, the IIS_IUSRS group got removed from "Impersonate a client after authentication" in Local Security Policy. I have hosted a web application under IIS, with Windows Authentication. The app pool runs under a domain account not the default applicationpool identity.

I cannot add back the IIS_IUSRS as I do not have permissions and the Admins are not willing to add it.

I am getting 500.0.1346 error when static files are served(css, js file). Here is the error "Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid.
(0x80070542)"

I can get around by adding the domain account under administrators group ( I think I should not add the domain account under admin group).

Is there a work around to fix this error?

Comment: Are you asking how to add that privilege back to IIS_IUSRS?

Comment: How could you work around it when your whole access system relies on what the domain controller decides to allow?  Like Andrew said, update the question to ask how to add that privilege back as the question and someone will likely find it and answer.

Comment: I cannot add it back. I do not have permissions. Our Admins are not willing to add it.

Comment: @PranayDevOps Then tell your manager that that the website cannot work and why, and please can they get the admins to provision another webserver for the task which has the required permissions.

Comment: ^ this ..  but in my experience it seems like the logical thing of asking someone to spend 5 minutes clicking a few things is too easy, they need you to build an 40 hour alternative from scratch .. thats the 'easiest' solution from some managers for some reason ..

Comment: Except by adding the custom AD account for the app pool to the local Admin group on the server, you can only add `IIS_IUSRS` account to "Impersonate a client after authentication" permission list in the local group policy.